# Rendering an animated model from three.js to p5.js

Tags: p5.js

I have animations working on p5 with still objs being swapped in and out but this will require a lot of stills and saving every frame to the computer and be a real hassle. I need to use p5js as I built the whole program in it I just need to be able to do all the calculations needed in three.js and turn all the models and textures after being rendered into p5 vertices and texture images. I asked open ai and it said something like this would work.

```
// Load the glTF model into Three.js
var loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
loader.load("model.gltf", function (gltf) {
  // Get the Three.js scene, camera, and renderer
  var scene = gltf.scene;
  var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
    60,
    window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
    0.1,
    1000
  );
  camera.position.z = 5;
  var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

  // Append the Three.js renderer to the DOM
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  // Get the skeleton and animations from the glTF model
  var skeleton = new THREE.SkeletonHelper(scene);
  var mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer(scene);
  gltf.animations.forEach(function (animation) {
    mixer.clipAction(animation).play();
  });

  // Render the model using p5.js's WebGL renderer
  function setup() {
    createCanvas(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight, WEBGL);
  }

  function draw() {
    background(200);
    translate(-width / 2, -height / 2);
    rotateX(frameCount * 0.01);
    rotateY(frameCount * 0.02);
    scale(50);

    // Update the animation
    mixer.update(1 / 60);

    // Get the vertices and textures from the Three.js mesh
    var vertices = scene.children[0].geometry.vertices;
    var textures = scene.children[0].material.map;

    // Convert the vertices into p5.js vertex objects
    var p5Vertices = vertices.map(function (vertex) {
      return createVector(vertex.x, vertex.y, vertex.z);
    });

    // Create a texture from the Three.js texture
    var p5Texture = createImage(textures.image.src);

    // Render the character using p5.js's WebGL renderer
    beginShape(TRIANGLES);
    for (var i = 0; i < vertices.length; i += 3) {
      texture(p5Texture);
      vertex(
        p5Vertices[i].x,
        p5Vertices[i].y,
        p5Vertices[i].z,
        textures[i].u,
        textures[i].v
      );
      vertex(
        p5Vertices[i + 1].x,
        p5Vertices[i + 1].y,
        p5Vertices[i + 1].z,
        textures[i + 1].u,
        textures[i + 1].v
      );
      vertex(
        p5Vertices[i + 2].x,
        p5Vertices[i + 2].y,
        p5Vertices[i + 2].z,
        textures[i + 2].u,
        textures[i + 2].v
      );
    }
    endShape();
  }
});
```

But I tried it and it just makes a black screen. I think it is close to what I need to do. I like the p5 simplicity and stuff I just need the models and textures from three.js is there any way to do this?

I tried putting in the p5 js editor the code that was given to me from open ai I was expecting a model to be displayed but a black screen was there. I think there must be a way to do this as three.js can bake the image and the vertices if the web canvas is the same settings and everything should also be the same I think. Then I bake all the images of the animation at run time after the first run and store them.
**Edit**
so thanks to Paul Wheeler the animation is working now I wanted to bake the texture with just some ambient light. so I did
//make a camera we are going to have to bake the texture once.

```
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75,window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,0.1,1000);
camera.position.z = 35;
const ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 0.5);
const scene = new THREE.Scene();
scene.add(ambientLight);
//now we can render with some light once to get the image 
//this function will convert our image to a loadable image for p5js
async function loadTexturesToMesh(bitmap, mesh,p) { // create ambient light with color #ffffff and intensity 0.5
bitmap=bitmap.data;
var width=bitmap.width,
  height=bitmap.height;
  const imageBitmap = await createImageBitmap(bitmap);
  const image = await loadImageFromBitmap(imageBitmap);
  image.width=width;
  image.height=height;
  image.src+="#ext=.png";
  p.loadImage(image.src,(image)=>mesh.image=image);
}
function loadImageFromBitmap(bitmap) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    // Convert ImageBitmap to Blob
    bitmapToBlob(bitmap)
      .then(blob => {
        // Load the blob into an Image object
        const image = new Image();
        image.onload = () => resolve(image);
        image.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob,{type:"image/png"});
      });
  });
}
function bitmapToBlob(bitmap) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.width = bitmap.width;
    canvas.height = bitmap.height;
    canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(bitmap, 0, 0);
    canvas.toBlob(blob => resolve(blob));
  });
}
```

Then we can use

```
if(!obj.material.map.loadingTextures)loadTexturesToMesh(obj.material.map.source,obj,p)
        obj.material.map.loadingTextures=true;
if(obj.image){
          p.texture(obj.image);
}
```

in the render function.

```
and this gltf => {
    var model = gltf.scene;

    scene.add(model);
    scene.add(ambientLight);
    renderer.render(model,camera);
```

to when it loads the glft to bake the image.

It bakes fine but the image doesn't wrap the model at all. IDK what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question on principle because I think asking Open AI to write the code you want and then asking Stack Overflow to fix it for you is not an acceptable strategy. If you want to accomplish something you should first research potential solutions and understand the libraries or concepts you are trying to leverage, once you have done your due diligence and are still stuck on a specific roadblock then it makes sense to ask on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @PaulWheeler just want some idea of how to do it. I have seen no examples or tutorials so of course I have to ask open ai.

Comment: Also I think a lot of people would want to know how todo it even if I am not the one to ask the question. In case someone does know.

Comment: I am suggesting that you change your strategy. When I don't know how to do something like this I would first read the relevant documentation for p5.js (specifically `texture`, `beginShape`, and `vertex`; although `p5.Geometry` by also be of interest for performance reasons), then I would read the relevant documentation for three.js (specifically `GLTFLoader`, `AnimationMixer`, and `scene.geometry`), based on the documentation of those topics I should be able to ascertain the feasibility and then make my own best effort to implement the integration, rather than asking an AI to do it.

Comment: I hear I should look into it. It might take me a while though, like two years I would have to go into the inner workings of the two and see if there is a way they are compatible I am not on that level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Euclid said "There is no royal road to geometry," but then he didn't have StackOverflow. Curiosity got the better of me, so here you go...

GLTFLoader's `.load` function invokes the callback with an object that has the following properties:

- `animations` // Array<THREE.AnimationClip>
- `scene` // THREE.Group
- `scenes` // Array<THREE.Group>
- `cameras` // Array<THREE.Camera>
- `asset` // Object

The main one we care about is `scene` which is a `Group`. A Group is a kind of `Object3D` that just contains child objects in its `children` property. Each of those children is itself some kind of `Object3D`. In my testing I only encounters `Object3D` which seems just like `Group` to me, and `Mesh` which is the actual 3d models. You cannot just assume that you only care about the first child of the scene Group like that garbage OpenAPI vomited at you. Instead you need to recursively process the tree of objects and render the Meshes.

Meshes contain a `BufferGeometry` object in there `geometry` property and that contains several critical components:

- `index` - a list of vertex indices that make up the mesh
- `attributes.position` - the x, y, and z coordinates of the vertices referenced by entries in index
- `attributes.normal` - the x, y, and z components of normal vectors for each vertex (normals are used to determine how much a face should be illuminated by a light source).

Armed with this knowledge we can simply iterate over the index list and draw vertices that are part of a `TRIANGLES` shape similar to what OpenAPI suggested.

However, before we do that there are a few considerations to take in mind:

1. The way positions and normals are extracted from their respective attributes was not obvious, so I used the `fromBufferAttribute` function on `Vector3`.
2. Instances of Object3D have their own positions, rotations, and scales. If I'm not mistaken these are all composed into the `matrixWorld` property, which happily appears to be compatible with p5.js's `applyMatrix`.
3. The size of the model may not fit well with p5.js's default camera setup, so you may need to tweak the scale for your particular model file.
4. The BufferGeometry object also has a `groups` property which is used to draw the mesh in multiple chunks, the code really ought to respect that, which it doesn't currently.
5. It is very likely that there are other object types in Three.js that I have not discussed and the code does not support.

References:

- [GLTFLoader](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#examples/en/loaders/GLTFLoader)
- [Group](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/objects/Group)
- [Mesh](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/objects/Mesh)
- [BufferGeometry](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/BufferGeometry)
- [Vector3](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/math/Vector3)

```css
html, body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.6.0/p5.js"></script>
<script async src="https://unpkg.com/es-module-shims@1.6.3/dist/es-module-shims.js"></script>

<script type="importmap">
  {
    "imports": {
      "three": "https://unpkg.com/three@0.150.1/build/three.module.js",
      "three/addons/": "https://unpkg.com/three@0.150.1/examples/jsm/"
    }
  }
</script>
<script type="module">
import { Vector3 } from 'three';
import { GLTFLoader } from 'three/addons/loaders/GLTFLoader.js';

function sketch(p) {
  p.setup = () => {
    p.createCanvas(p.windowWidth, p.windowHeight, p.WEBGL);
    p.background(100);
  };

  // Loading Screen
  p.draw = () => {
    p.circle(p.mouseX, p.mouseY, 20);
  }

  function renderObject(obj) {
    switch (obj.type) {
      case 'Object3D':
      case 'Group':
        for (const child of obj.children) {
          renderObject(child);
        }
        break;
      case 'Mesh':
        p.push();
        p.applyMatrix(obj.matrixWorld.elements);
        p.beginShape(p.TRIANGLES);
        let pos = new Vector3();
        let norm = new Vector3();
        for (const ix of obj.geometry.index.array) {
          pos.fromBufferAttribute(obj.geometry.attributes.position, ix);
          norm.fromBufferAttribute(obj.geometry.attributes.normal, ix);

          p.normal(norm.x, norm.y, norm.z);
          p.vertex(pos.x, pos.y, pos.z);
        }

        p.endShape();
        p.pop();
        break;
      default:
        throw new Error(`Unsupported Object Type: {obj.type}`);
    }
  }

  const loader = new GLTFLoader();
  loader.load(
    'https://www.paulwheeler.us/files/BoxAnimated.gltf',
    gltf => {
      p.draw = () => {
        p.background(0);
        p.orbitControl(8, 4, 0.1);

        p.scale(100);
        p.noStroke();
        p.normalMaterial();
        renderObject(gltf.scene);
      }
    }
  );
}

new p5(sketch);

console.log(`
The file BoxAnimated.gltf provided by [Cesium](http://cesiumjs.org/) for glTF testing.

This model is licensed under a [Creative Commons Attribution 4.0 International License](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/)
`);
</script>
```

I know you were also interested in animation, but I think I've given you a lot to go on. Read more Three.js API documentation and you should be able to figure it out.

---

### Critique of OpenAI

Things OpenAI got wrong:

1. You don't need all the `WebGLRenderer` and `PerspectiveCamera` stuff since you aren't rendering with Three.js, you're rendering with p5.js
2. As previously mentioned, you can just assume that `scene` is a single child `Group` containing a `Mesh`
3. Its attempt to access `vertices` for the `Mesh` geometry is incorrect (perhaps this is from an outdated version of Three.js or a different type of `geometry`
4. It didn't take vertex normals into consideration
5. It's not technically wrong, but there is no reason to convert Three.js `Vector3` objects into `p5.Vector` objects with `createVector` when all you are going to do is access their `x`, `y`, and `z` components

OpenAI should be considered harmful for programming and all other forms of creative knowledge work. Most of the time it will give you crap that looks right but doesn't pass muster, and when it works it is just tantamount to either cheating or stealing someone else's work. When you succeed using OpenAI you just end up failing in he long run because you didn't gain the knowledge for your self and are therefore building on a house of cards. If you are diligent you will find it doesn't actually take years to get to where you want to go. There truly is no royal road to being a good computer programmer.

---

### UPDATE: Working Animation

I went back and figured out how to get animation working. The important bits are:

Create an `AnimationMixer` instance for the target object.

```
let animator = new AnimationMixer(gltf.scene);
```

Tell the `AnimationMixer` to play the desired animation (Note: some GLTF files may have multiple animations for different actions or effects, here we just assume there is at least one and play the first one).

```
let animation = gltf.animations[0];
animator.clipAction(animation).play();
```

Update the AnimationMixer each frame:

```
animator.update(p.deltaTime / 1000);
```

Because the animation updates translations and rotations, we need to have the scene recompute the transformation matrices:

```
gltf.scene.updateMatrixWorld();
```

Here's a version of the snippet with animation working:

```css
html, body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.6.0/p5.js"></script>
<script async src="https://unpkg.com/es-module-shims@1.6.3/dist/es-module-shims.js"></script>

<script type="importmap">
  {
    "imports": {
      "three": "https://unpkg.com/three@0.150.1/build/three.module.js",
      "three/addons/": "https://unpkg.com/three@0.150.1/examples/jsm/"
    }
  }
</script>
<script type="module">
import { AnimationMixer, Vector3 } from 'three';
import { GLTFLoader } from 'three/addons/loaders/GLTFLoader.js';

function sketch(p) {
  p.setup = () => {
    p.createCanvas(p.windowWidth, p.windowHeight, p.WEBGL);
    p.background(100);
  };

  // Loading Screen
  p.draw = () => {
    p.circle(p.mouseX, p.mouseY, 20);
  }

  function renderObject(obj) {
    switch (obj.type) {
      case 'Object3D':
      case 'Group':
        for (const child of obj.children) {
          renderObject(child);
        }
        break;
      case 'Mesh':
        p.push();
        p.applyMatrix(obj.matrixWorld.elements);
        p.beginShape(p.TRIANGLES);
        let pos = new Vector3();
        let norm = new Vector3();
        for (const ix of obj.geometry.index.array) {
          pos.fromBufferAttribute(obj.geometry.attributes.position, ix);
          norm.fromBufferAttribute(obj.geometry.attributes.normal, ix);

          p.normal(norm.x, norm.y, norm.z);
          p.vertex(pos.x, pos.y, pos.z);
        }

        p.endShape();
        p.pop();
        break;
      default:
        throw new Error(`Unsupported Object Type: {obj.type}`);
    }
  }

  const loader = new GLTFLoader();
  loader.load(
    'https://www.paulwheeler.us/files/BoxAnimated.gltf',
    gltf => {
      let animator = new AnimationMixer(gltf.scene);
      console.log(`There are ${gltf.animations.length} animations. Auto-playing the first one.`);
      let animation = gltf.animations[0];
      animator.clipAction(animation).play();
            
      p.draw = () => {
        p.background(0);
        p.orbitControl(8, 4, 0.1);
        
        p.scale(100);
        p.noStroke();
        p.normalMaterial();
        
        animator.update(p.deltaTime / 1000);
        gltf.scene.updateMatrixWorld();
        renderObject(gltf.scene);
      }
    }
  );
}

new p5(sketch);

console.log(`
The file BoxAnimated.gltf provided by [Cesium](http://cesiumjs.org/) for glTF testing.

This model is licensed under a [Creative Commons Attribution 4.0 International License](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/)
`);
</script>
```

Comment: Really nice answer(+1). (I was considering a hacky workaround to render three.js stuff in an offline buffer/canvas that could be wrapped as p5.Image (from canvas) to be rendered/compositied into p5.js (via `image`), but this is much cleaner. Porting the p5.js code to three.js sounds simpler, but that's not what the OP was after). I appreciate you're taking the time to diligently document this for the benefit of others.

Comment: I know you were also interested in animation, but I think I've given you a lot to go on. Read more Three.js API documentation and you should be able to figure it out. I did thank you so much here is the link https://editor.p5js.org/byersolomon/sketches/x7gr3wVs_. It's really interesting.

Comment: I'm glad you were able to get animation working. I do think the example you linked to can be streamlined a little bit. See my update to the answer for some explanation of what is needed.

Comment: @PaulWheeler check out the new code I added texture from the color and the scale from the model. https://editor.p5js.org/byersolomon/sketches/x7gr3wVs_. I think this is like groundbreaking stuff. I can't do the fancy shadows I don't think

Comment: @PaulWheeler I got a baked texture and everything I had to run the scene once though!https://editor.p5js.org/byersolomon/sketches/6-eE5QAYH I used the model on local host I can't upload it to p5 it is 15mib I used https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Sample-Models/blob/master/2.0/BoomBox/glTF/BoomBox.gltf in case your interested. Wow It's really interesting. Now I can finish my app Thanks again!:)

Comment: I almost have skeletons working https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75796344/rendering-a-skeleten-glb-in-p5js.

Comment: Ok got it! https://editor.p5js.org/byersolomon/sketches/h7LSGt_yI Skeletons are working bu yeah but slow the obj.boneTransform( ix, pos );
              obj.boneTransform( ix, norm ); are expensive