# Rendering a skeleten glb in p5js

Tags: p5.js

so I have a way to render a model [Rendering an animated model from three.js to p5.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75715609/rendering-an-animated-model-from-three-js-to-p5-js/75743250#75743250). But not with a skeleton I really just want to turn a skeleton model into a regular model with keyframes and a mesh. Is that possible?

I tried excuting the skeleton calculations but I don't know the math to do it and the calculations were all off.
Here is the ideas I had **EDIT** https://editor.p5js.org/byersolomon/sketches/D4jgx8VRr really this function.

```
var updateThis = [];

function updateSkinnedMesh() {
  requestAnimationFrame(updateSkinnedMesh);
  if (updateThis.length == 0) return;
  updateThis.forEach(obj => {
    var bones = obj.skeleton.bones;
    var boneMatrices = obj.skeleton.boneMatrices;
    var skinIndices = obj.geometry.attributes.skinIndex.array;
    var skinWeights = obj.geometry.attributes.skinWeight.array;
    var bindMatrix = obj.bindMatrix;
    var bindMatrixInverse = obj.bindMatrixInverse;

    // Initialize an array to store the transformed vertices
    var vertices = [];

    // Transform the vertices using the bone matrices
    for (var i = 0; i < obj.geometry.attributes.position.count; i++) {
      var vertex = new THREE.Vector3().fromBufferAttribute(obj.geometry.attributes.position, i);
      var skinIndex = skinIndices[i];
      var skinWeight = skinWeights[i];

      var boneMatrix = new THREE.Matrix4().fromArray(boneMatrices, skinIndex * 16);
      var bindMatrixInverse = new THREE.Matrix4().fromArray(boneMatrices);
      bindMatrixInverse.invert();
      var bindVector = vertex.applyMatrix4(bindMatrix);
      var worldVector = bindVector.applyMatrix4(boneMatrix);
      var transformed = worldVector.applyMatrix4(bindMatrixInverse);

      // Apply skinning weights to the transformed vertex
      vertex.lerp(transformed, skinWeight);
      vertices.push(vertex);
    }

    // Update the transformed vertices in the geometry
    var position = new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute(vertices.length * 3, 3);
    for (var i = 0; i < vertices.length; i++) {
      position.setXYZ(i, vertices[i].x, vertices[i].y, vertices[i].z);
    }
    obj.geometry.setAttribute('position', position);

    obj.updateMatrixWorld();
  });
}
```

But I think I am just going about this the wrong way I am not a mathmatition I just want a program online or otherwise that will compute the stuff and spit out another glb with keyframes instead of a skeleton.

EDIT
so I got close I just need a little bit to finish it off. What is wrong with this function.

```
case "SkinnedMesh":
          obj.updating = true;
          p.push();
          try {
            var color = obj.material.color;
            if (color) p.fill(color.r * 255, color.g * 255, color.b * 255);
            if (!obj.material.loadingTextures) loadTexturesToMesh(obj.material.map, obj, p)
            obj.material.loadingTextures = true;
          } catch (e) {
            obj.material = {};
            obj.material.loadingTextures = true;
            var color = obj.material.color = false;
          }
          //use the image once the previous function loads it
          if (obj.image) {
            try {
              p.textureMode(p.NORMAL);
              p.textureWrap(p.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
              // p.texture(obj.image);
            } catch (e) { }
          }
          p.applyMatrix(obj.matrixWorld.elements);
          p.beginShape(p.TRIANGLES);
          var pos = new Vector3();
          var norm = new Vector3();
          var texAttr = new Vector2();

          var x = 0, y = 0;
         //an array of all the vectors and bones
          if (obj.bonesVertexNormal) {
            for (const array of obj.bonesVertexNormal) {
              var closestBone = array[0];
              var pos = array[1];
              var norm = array[2];
              var texAttr = array[3];
              obj.localToWorld(pos);
              closestBone.worldToLocal(pos);
              obj.localToWorld(norm);
              closestBone.worldToLocal(norm);
              // obj.worldToLocal(norm);
              p.normal(norm.x, -norm.y, norm.z);
              p.vertex(pos.x, pos.y, pos.z);
            }
            p.endShape();
            p.pop();
          } else {
           //if the image is ready and the array not loaded load the array.
            if (!obj.image) {
              p.endShape();
              p.pop();
              break;
            }
            obj.bonesVertexNormal = [];
            for (const ix of obj.geometry.index.array) {
              pos.fromBufferAttribute(obj.geometry.attributes.position, ix);
              norm.fromBufferAttribute(obj.geometry.attributes.normal, ix);
              if (obj.image) { texAttr.fromBufferAttribute(obj.geometry.attributes.uv, ix); }
              const skinnedMesh = obj // your SkinnedMesh object
              const point = pos // the point you want to find the closest bone to

              // Get the world position of the SkinnedMesh object

              // Find the closest bone to the given point
              let closestDistance = Number.MAX_VALUE;
              let closestBone = null;
              skinnedMesh.skeleton.bones.forEach(bone => {
                const bonePosition =  bone.position;
                const distance = p.dist(pos.x,pos.y,pos.z,bonePosition.x,bonePosition.y,bonePosition.z);
                if (distance < closestDistance) {
                  closestDistance = distance;
                  closestBone = bone;
                }
              });

              obj.bonesVertexNormal.push([closestBone,pos.copy(new Vector3()),norm.copy(new Vector3()),texAttr.copy(new Vector2())]);
            p.endShape();
            p.pop();
          }
          break;
```

Edit I needed to apply the weights and get the right boned still not really working but I think I am close.

```
case "SkinnedMesh":
         //from right hand to left 
        var convertToP5=(vec) => {
 var vec2=new Vector3().copy(vec);
  vec2.x=vec.x;
  vec2.y=vec.z;
  vec2.z=-vec.y;
  vec.x=vec2.x;
  vec.y=vec2.y;
  vec.z=vec2.z;
  return vec;
}
 //from left hand to right 
var convertToThree=(vec) => {
 var vec2=new Vector3().copy(vec);
  vec2.x=vec.x;
  vec2.y=-vec.z;
  vec2.z=vec.y;
  vec.x=vec2.x;
  vec.y=vec2.y;
  vec.z=vec2.z;
  return vec;
}
          obj.updating = true;
          var skinnedMesh=obj;
          p.push();
          try {
            var color = obj.material.color;
            if (color) p.fill(color.r * 255, color.g * 255, color.b * 255);
            if (!obj.material.loadingTextures) loadTexturesToMesh(obj.material.map, obj, p)
            obj.material.loadingTextures = true;
          } catch (e) {
            obj.material = {};
            obj.material.loadingTextures = true;
            var color = obj.material.color = false;
          }
          if (obj.image) {
            try {
              p.textureMode(p.NORMAL);
              p.textureWrap(p.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
              // p.texture(obj.image);
            } catch (e) { }
          }
          p.applyMatrix(obj.matrixWorld.elements);
          p.beginShape(p.TRIANGLES);
          var pos = new Vector3();
          var norm = new Vector3();
          var texAttr = new Vector2();
          
          const skinIndex = new THREE.Vector4();
          const skinWeight = new THREE.Vector4();

          var x = 0, y = 0;
          
            if (!obj.image) {
              p.endShape();
              p.pop();
              break;
            }
            var bones=obj.skeleton.bones;
            for (const ix of obj.geometry.index.array) {
              pos.fromBufferAttribute(obj.geometry.attributes.position, ix);
              norm.fromBufferAttribute(obj.geometry.attributes.normal, ix);
            skinIndex.fromBufferAttribute(obj.geometry.attributes.skinIndex, ix);
            skinWeight.fromBufferAttribute(obj.geometry.attributes.skinWeight, ix);
              if (obj.image) { texAttr.fromBufferAttribute(obj.geometry.attributes.uv, ix); }
              const boneMatrices = skinnedMesh.skeleton.boneMatrices;
              const vertexPos = convertToThree(pos);
const transformedPos = new THREE.Vector3();
for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  const boneIndex = skinIndex.getComponent(i);
  const weightedPos = new THREE.Vector3().copy(pos);
  const boneMatrix = bones[bones.length-1-boneIndex].localToWorld(weightedPos);
weightedPos.multiplyScalar(skinWeight.getComponent(i));
  transformedPos.add(weightedPos);
}
const vertexNorm = convertToThree(norm);
const transformedNorm = new THREE.Vector3();
for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  const boneIndex = skinIndex.getComponent(i);
  const weightedPos = new THREE.Vector3().copy(norm);
  const boneMatrix = bones[bones.length-1-boneIndex].localToWorld(weightedPos);

weightedPos.multiplyScalar(skinWeight.getComponent(i))
  transformedNorm.add(weightedPos);
}
convertToP5(transformedNorm);
convertToP5(transformedPos);
p.normal(transformedNorm.x, transformedNorm.y, transformedNorm.z);
p.vertex(transformedPos.x, transformedPos.y, transformedPos.z);
             
            }
            p.endShape();
            p.pop();
          break;
```

Comment: Added but I am really just looking for a program if anyone knows that will convert from skeleton to non.